# No keyboard layouts in Cinnamon 2.6.7

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I upgraded my Cinnamon DE (in Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca) via `sudo apt-get install cinnamon`, from my Xfce DE. All is working well except for the keyboard layouts. I'm stuck with a US English layout and the options are blank:

[image]

On the terminal, `dpkg -l | grep '^ii *cinnamon' | awk '{print $2}'` gives:

```
cinnamon
cinnamon-bluetooth
cinnamon-common
cinnamon-control-center
cinnamon-control-center-data
cinnamon-desktop-data
cinnamon-screensaver
cinnamon-session
cinnamon-session-common
cinnamon-settings-daemon
cinnamon-themes
cinnamon-translations
```

Any suggestions? Am I missing some package?

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. Editing your post is the same as bumping it, it goes back to the front page. Posting again doesn't help you and in fact will get you automatically banned by the system (something the mods have no control over) if you do it too often.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing some packages. I don't use Ubuntu but I'm pretty sure the package you wanted to install was `cinnamon-desktop` and not `cinnamon`. The latter does not seem to contain all the necessary bits.

Try installing the missing packages and restarting Cinnamon:

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

The `cinnamon-desktop-environment` is an Ubuntu meta package that should install *everything* that comes with Cinnamon. While that will almost certainly solve your issue, it will also install various programs that you might not necessarily want (things like `pidgin`, `totem` etc).

You could also try installing the `cinnamon-desktop-core` metapackage which should bring in everything you need (though you seem to have most of it already) without too many extras.

Comment: I tried both, and it's still the same. I guess I should just reinstall Mint from scratch, although I'm sort of on the move and it's not the best of times for that. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @BernatBardagil also try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cinnamon-desktop-environment`.